# How to mix butter with meat

Tags: meat, butter, hamburgers

I work in a burger factory and I have a question about a product we are trying to produce. We want to create a burger patty with butter in it. But when we mix all the ingredients (mostly ground meat and butter) in a metal device, most of the butter sticks to the metallic side instead of blending with the meat. Any ideas?

Comment: My first thought is that you would have better luck on SeasonedAdvice.SE (cooking site). Still, it seems slightly surprising that since the ground meat (if it's hamburger beef) is probably 20% fats, I'd think that another fatty product would be more miscible with the meat fat. What is the consistency of the buter (i.e. hard, soft, melted) and what are the relative portions (i.e. 1 part butter to 4 parts meat, etc.)? Can you use a softer butter substitute instead?

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply. The meat is less then 20% fat. We tried using soft and melted butter, still aboute 80 % butter stuck to the metal mixer. I cant remember the actual beaf to butter ratio. I thought to try an emulsefire. Because the meat might be too lipophobic

Comment: I agree that this might be better at Seasoned Advice. Have you tried clarified butter? It may be the water and milk solids in regular butter than are the problem. Also, instead of mixing, have you tried using a meat grinder to grind cold butter into the meat?

Comment: If the metal surfaces do not have the proper surface roughness, the surface could be too rough and allow things to stick to it. Please describe how the butter looks when it is added, as it begins to be mixed, and when it is stuck to metal surfaces.

Comment: Can you get 'non-stick' coated parts for the metal device?  You might want to think about an emulsifier ... try a small amount of mustard on a small scale ... if that works and you don't want mustard flavour, you need to look for a flavourless emulsifier.  Report back if those suggestions were of any used.

Comment: What kind of machine ? maybe you are using the wrong device ?

Comment: That's very curious.  I've mixed butter into ground beef by hand a few times and I never had that problem.  I suppose the pieces of meat must be coated with fat during the grinding process, which could repel the water in the butter.  So, the other comments that suggest using an emulsifier or clarified butter could be on the right track.  You may also consider trying butter with a higher fat content and/or adding some dried bread crumbs, dried onions, dried parsley, etc. to absorb some of the water from the butter.

Comment: If soft and melted butter didn't work, how about hard or frozen butter, grated or chopped small and folded into the mix after other mixing was finished?  It sounds like the soft butter is sticking, while hard butter should not smear around (though lots of little clumps will let it distribute anyway), and when it does soften most of the little clumps should be essentially surrounded by the rest of your mix, and melt into them, not the bowl.  I think.

Comment: Is using an absorbent medium -eg, soaking up the molten butter in bread, mincing the bread and adding it - an acceptable solution?

Comment: I'd try @Megha's suggestions

Comment: Huh.  I'm wondering what butter adds to beef that beef fat, of which there is usually plenty in burger beef, doesn't already offer.  But that's beyond the scope of OP's responsibilities and the question, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

+1 @megha Grating frozen (or very cold refrigerated) butter is the way to go here. It's best to add the grated butter to the mince after the meat has been ground. Grating butter is easily done in a food processor (industrial or home) - we did it all the time at an old restaurant I worked at and I still do it at home for pastry crust.

Random source: 
http://people.com/food/grated-butter-burgers-recipe-food-hack/

**Alternative idea** - America's Test Kitchen did a Butter Burger bit awhile back that people claim is amazing: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAUpelESAXo